# Align square root symbols in equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I have the following equation in my tex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    x_{ij} = \frac{
                \sum_{t}{e_i(t)e_j(t)}
             } { 
                \sqrt{\sum_t{e_i^2(t)}} 
                \sqrt{\sum_t{e_j^2(t)}}
             }
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The equation is printed like this:

[image: demo equation]

The problem is that despite having almost the same content, the two square root symbols are rendered with a different size.

Is it possible to equalize the size of the two square root symbols?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    x_{ij} = \frac{
                \sum_{t}{e_i(t)e_j(t)}
             } { 
                \sqrt{\strut\sum_t{e_i^2(t)}} 
                \sqrt{\strut\sum_t{e_j^2(t)}}
             }
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Square roots are very sensitive to ascenders and descenders. Just look at the two of them and you'll realize that the culprit is the `j` in the second one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  x_{ij} =
  \frac{
        \sum_{t}{e_i(t)e_j(t)}
       }
       {
        \sqrt{\sum_t{e_{i\vphantom{j}}^2(t)}}
        \sqrt{\sum_t{e_j^2(t)}}
       }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it may be a good idea to have `\mathstrut` in the exponents, so they don't risk touching the vinculum.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  x_{ij} =
  \frac{
        \sum_{t}{e_i(t)e_j(t)}
       }
       {
        \sqrt{\sum_t{e_{i}^{\mathstrut 2}(t)}}
        \sqrt{\sum_t{e_{j}^{\mathstrut 2}(t)}}
       }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 2):

More of a workaround than a regular answer to your question: using `\limits`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    x_{ij} = \frac{
                \sum\limits_{t}{e_i(t)e_j(t)}
             } { 
                \sqrt{\sum\limits_t{e_i^2(t)}} 
                \sqrt{\sum\limits_t{e_j^2(t)}}
             }
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the radical signs are really too large, and the use of `\limits` spaces the numerator farther from the fraction line than desirable.  a publisher's copyeditor would probably reject this formulation.